# How can I move this search form? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

right now I have a page like this

[image]

and what I want to get it is something like this:

[image]

I've been searching for tutorials and stuff like this but I'm still stuck at this. My code is:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
     <div id="containerHeader">
      <h1>Seek & enjoy</h1>
      <h3>Your movie seeker</h3>
       <div id="containerForm">
         <form class="form-wrapper cf">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Find your movie"
          required>
         <button type="submit">Seek</button>
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
#containerHeader {
    background-color: #D1D0CE;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Clearing Floats*/
.cf:before, .cf:after{
    content:"";
    display:table; 
}

.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}

.cf{
    zoom:1;
}

/* Form wrapper styling */
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I posted just CSS code I think it's necessary to work out this problem. Most of that CSS code is not mine, I'm quite new at CSS. I think that the solution is in using properly `position` but I don't use it properly yet. Any idea? Please, if something in my question is not correct let me know to edit it.

Thanks

Comment: The form has 150px of top margin which obviously places it 150px below the title.

Comment: Thanks both, you had right. It's already solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's the `margin-top: 150px` you have in the shorthand margin of your CSS: `margin: 150px auto 50px auto;`. Changing that to a smaller number will decrease the size of the gap.

Comment: Exactly, I didn't realize about that. I thought it was about `position. Thanks @JohnTobin

Answer (score 0):

In this you should decrease the margin.

```
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

But with this you have to increase your container padding for your background color.

```
#containerHeader {
    background-color: #D1D0CE;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change margin-top value.
Its 150px in your case

Answer (score 0):

You wrong on your margin

```
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your margin.

```
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

since you want to reduce the distance between the text and search form, you need to change the value of `margin-top` which in this case is `150px`. Try changing it to `40px` for example. The 4 values from left to right represent margin `top`, `right`, `bottom` and  `left`.

Here's some [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kikabuwicico/1/edit?html,css,output).